# How to select for "any and all possible values"

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's a list of chatrooms. Currently, if you join a room by clicking enter, it'll open the chatroom by appending a `div` of the chatroom. So if you click multiple rooms, it'll open multiple rooms.
I would like to make sure that only one room can be open at any given time. So, if a room is open and the user clicks to open another room, *any other* open room should close.

This is code that shows the addition of a chatroom to a `div` with an ID of `chats`:

```
if (data.join) {
    console.log("Joining room " + data.join);
    var roomdiv = $(
        "<div class='room' id='room-" + data.join + "'>" +
        "<h2>" + data.title + "</h2>" +
        "<div class='messages'></div>" +
        "<input><button>Send</button>" +
        "</div>"
    );
    $("#chats").append(roomdiv);
```

I'd like to add a bit of code to make sure that all open rooms close before opening another one. Here is the same code with the addition that I plan on making:

```
  if (data.join) {
      console.log("Joining room " + data.join);
      var roomdiv = $(
          "<div class='room' id='room-" + data.join + "'>" +
          "<h2>" + data.title + "</h2>" +
          "<div class='messages'></div>" +
          "<input><button>Send</button>" +
          "</div>"
      );
      $("#room-" + * ).remove(roomdiv);
      $("#chats").append(roomdiv);
```

This line `$("#room-" + *).remove(roomdiv);` doesn't work. I'd like to implement something here that says any attributes with ID `room-`(*/anything) should be removed.

What's the proper way to go about this?

Comment: You should perhaps have only one chat div and change its content to the currently selected chat. This is better to manage I think

Comment: Kinda like an SPA

Comment: Simple `(".room").remove();` will work

Comment: Maybe `$("#chats").html(roomdiv);`

Comment: @skobaljic Indeed...

Comment: @Phiter Youre suggesting that I not create the `roomdiv` every time, yeah? Simply hardcode the div in once, and only change it's ID or class dynamically?

Comment: Homer, I'd not change the div ID for  that purpose. Try putting the id like `chat-div` and leave the class. If you want the div to hold the chat_id somewhere, you can use `data-*` attributes, which is way better and widely supported. Something like `<div id="chat-div" class="chat" data-chat-id="5"></div>`. Then you can get the current chat ID using `$("#chat-div").data('chatId');`

Comment: @Phiter did you mean using `$("#chat-div").data('data-chat-id');` ?

Comment: No, `data(` will take any attributes starting with `data-*`. See: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All existing rooms have the class `room`. You can remove all of them at once using `$('.room').remove()` before creating and appending your new room.

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `^` JQuery selector, it will select everything starting with ... :

```
$("[id^='room-']").remove(roomdiv);
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the single quotes.